# Parsing DateTime From VB.NET to Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

I've been struggling with Oracle's Date Time Function.

I have stored procedure which runs properly and well done but I don't have any idea how can I parsing the date from VB.net so that the stored procedure can receive the value from VB.net?

Does anyone know how to parsing the value from VB.net, in this case I talk about the Date Time so it will be a hour, second and minute.

Thank you so much

Here's the .NET code

```
Try
            Dim conn As New OracleConnection(connectionString(data(0), data(1), data(2)))
            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "transactionme"
            Dim p1 As OracleParameter
            Dim p2 As OracleParameter
            Dim p3 As OracleParameter
            Dim p4 As OracleParameter
            Dim p5 As OracleParameter
            Dim p6 As OracleParameter
            Dim p7 As OracleParameter
            Dim p8 As OracleParameter
            Dim p9 As OracleParameter
            Dim p10 As OracleParameter
            p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("param1", OracleDbType.NChar)
            p1.Value = ""
            p2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("param2", OracleDbType.NChar)
            p2.Value = "STD2"
            p3 = cmd.Parameters.Add("param3", OracleDbType.NChar)
            p3.Value = "RK001"
            p4 = cmd.Parameters.Add("param4", OracleDbType.NChar)
            p4.Value = "EK001"
            p5 = cmd.Parameters.Add("param5", OracleDbType.Date)
            p5.Value = "here is the problem"
            p6 = cmd.Parameters.Add("param6", OracleDbType.Date)
            p6.Value = "here is the problem"
            p7 = cmd.Parameters.Add("param7", OracleDbType.Date)
            p7.Value = "here is the problem"
            p8 = cmd.Parameters.Add("param8", OracleDbType.NChar)
            p8.Value = "Master Card"
            p9 = cmd.Parameters.Add("param9", OracleDbType.Int32)
            p9.Value = 30000

            Dim n As Integer
            n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show(n.ToString)
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

The parameter should be like this, have tried many things like concat and others

```
to_date('2012-01-23 22:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here.  Does the procedure take a `VARCHAR2`?  A `DATE`?  A `TIMESTAMP`?  An `INTERVAL`?  If the procedure takes a `VARCHAR2`, what does the string look like?  What are you trying to parse from the string?

Comment: Edited guys, please kindly have a look, thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to this [MSDN Forum Posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/99acc52c-6eb3-48be-8453-907deefc9d8a) the Oracle Date data type corresponds to the .Net Date data type.

From above Link:

> The parameter value should be a Date data value and not a string. There is no need to format the date when you're passing it in as a parameter since the underlying representation is numeric.

i.e.

```
p5 = cmd.Parameters.Add("param5", OracleDbType.Date)  
p5.Value = Convert.ToDateTime("Your Date here")
```

Edit try this to Parse your Date/time information and Convert your string.

```
  Private Function GetDateTime(dateFormat As String) As Date
    Dim split() As String = New String() {","}

    Return Convert.ToDateTime(dateFormat.Split(split, 2, StringSplitOptions.None)(0))

End Function
```

usage:

```
p5.Value = GetDateTime("2012-01-23 22:00, YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi") 'or what ever your string variable is.
```

Comment: p5 = cmd.Parameters.Add("param5", OracleDbType.Date)
            p5.Value = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-01-23 22:00, YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi")

I've tried this but unfortunately there's an error because the String is not valid, can you give me a light how to do this properly?

Comment: @BigSmile You do not need the formating if you just use `Convert.ToDateTime("2012-01-23 22:00")` it will work.

Comment: what is inside the newDate? Thank you

Comment: @BigSmile  Sorry that is your datetime string ("2012-01-23 22:00, YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi" let me see if I can clarify it a little bit better in the answer

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime(newDate.Split( raises error sir --->split, 2, StringSplitOptions.None)(0))

Comment: @BigSmile Sorry I forgot to include the split string array, I have enclosed it in a function, see if it works for you now

Comment: I use oracle data access but unfortunately I can't run that script

Comment: @BigSmile That is a Visual Basic function not a script just like the connectionString function from the other day. What is the name of the string that you are setting p5.Value to?

Comment: @BigSmile I guess my main question is were is the format data coming from that is in your String that you are trying to convert, because if you are trying to convert to a DateTime object you do not need it, only when coming from a DateTime to a String. A DateTime object **does not** have formating