# Convert date string to oracle format

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I tried google and even this site but I cannot find a clear cut answer.. I am using vb.net and trying to convert a user entered date to a workable query string for oracle..

IE: Current Date: 10/16/2014
Output needs to be 16-OCT-2014

How can i convert in VB?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim myDate = Convert.ToDateTime("10/16/2014")
myDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy").ToUpper() ' displayed as 16-OCT-2014
```

You can see more custom formattings here: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

If you get rid of the `.ToUpper()`, then it shows up as `16-Oct-2014`

Note, you can also achieve the same thing with `String.Format()` using the format string with the index reference:

```
String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", myDate).ToUpper() ' also outputs 16-OCT-2014
```

---

On side note, as long as you are using parameterized queries ([and you should be](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev)), then I would imagine that your data connection should be taking care of that conversion. For example, if you were using the `OracleConnection` outlined [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/GettingStartedVBVersion/GettingStartedNET_VBVersion.htm), then you would use the [`ParameterCollection.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx) method as outlined in the following posts:

- [Parsing DateTime From VB.NET to Oracle Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321546/parsing-datetime-from-vb-net-to-oracle-stored-procedure)
- [Not a valid month error (ORA-1843) - Oracle "timestamp" column vs .NET DateTime](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99acc52c-6eb3-48be-8453-907deefc9d8a/not-a-valid-month-error-ora1843-oracle-timestamp-column-vs-net-datetime?forum=adodotnetdataproviders)
- [Getting Started with Oracle Data Provider for .NET (VB.NET Version)](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/GettingStartedVBVersion/GettingStartedNET_VBVersion.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String date = Convert.ToDatetime("10/16/2014").ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dim tmpDefaultCultureInfo As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")
dim tmpDateTimeFormatter As New System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo()

tmpDateTimeFormatter = CType(System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo)
tmpDateTimeFormatter.Calendar = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Calendar
tmpDateTimeFormatter.FullDateTimePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

dim tmpOracleDate as string = "TO_DATE('" & String.Format(tmpDefaultCultureInfo, "{0:" & tmpDateTimeFormatter.FullDateTimePattern & "}", yourDateTimeValue) & "','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')"
```